# Как добавить к имеющемуся обработчику событий свою функцию?

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка, которая создается не мной (Symfony). К ней опять-таки не мной (Bootstrap) привязывается обработчик из jQuery (то есть править его я не могу).

Как мне сделать, чтоб после "штатного" обработчика выполнился и мой скриптик?

Comment: Просто добавьте еще один обработчик через addEventListener

Comment: А он не перепишет штатный обработчик?

Comment: Нет. addEventListener создает новый обработчик. Только будьте аккуратны, каждый вызов addEventListener будет создавать новый обработчик.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @SwaD, если не ту же самую функцию добавляешь

Comment: @SwaD Получилось, спасибо. Только пришлось на свой обработчик ставить задержку выполнения через setTimeout() - похоже, он начинал выполнятьсчя одновременно с основным

Comment: @Confireus, обработчики выполняются строго последовательно, в порядке их добавления